# Updating an array object creates a new empty object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have an array of orders containing user ID, the amount and the order itself. Each user can only have one order at a time but I'm trying to add an option to edit your order. I created a method that is supposed to be doing that:

```
'click .edit': function (event) {
       var order = $('#editOrder').val();
       var price = $('#editPrice').val();
       Meteor.call('changeOrder', Router.current().data()._id, Meteor.userId(), order, price);
       Session.set("editing", false);
   },
changeOrder: function (id, user, order, amount) {

           Polls.update({_id: id, 'Orders.User': user}, {$set: {'Orders.$': {
                       User: user,
                       Order: order,
                       Amount: parseFloat(amount)
                   }}});
   },
```

This method actually works but the problem is every time I edit an order it creates a new object with the same user ID and empty Order and Amount properties.
I honestly have no idea what could be causing an update function to insert void data.
Here's an example of the Poll structure with the extra empty order:

```
{
"_id" : "4wGAPfxCvKfH4L8JL",
"Company" : "FirmaTest",
"Restaurants" : [ 
    "Trylinka", 
    "Da Grasso", 
    "Faster", 
    "Green Way", 
    "Telepizza", 
    "Piramida"
],
"Expires" : ISODate("2015-08-24T08:26:00.791Z"),
"Votes" : {
    "Trylinka" : 1,
    "Da Grasso" : 0,
    "Faster" : 2,
    "Green Way" : 3,
    "Telepizza" : 0,
    "Piramida" : 0
},
"Voted" : [ 
    "TfQM7954a5SHoR9os"
],
"Winner" : "Green Way",
"Orders" : [ 
    {
        "User" : "TfQM7954a5SHoR9os",
        "Order" : "Some chicken",
        "Amount" : 15
    }, 
    {
        "User" : "TfQM7954a5SHoR9os",
        "Order" : null,
        "Amount" : NaN
    }
],
"Ordered" : [ 
    "TfQM7954a5SHoR9os"
]
}
```

---

#### Solved

Turns out I was triggering a submit form located in the same page. Even though the event I was calling wasn't a 'form submit' it had a form in it and so the submit still went through. Also I used the same variable names in both the form submit and the button trigger so the insert methods still went through.
Thanks for the answers but it turns out the problem was somewhere else and my fault entirely :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are querying `_id` with a string instead an ObjectID?

Try converting the `id` into an ObjectID with:

```
new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(valuefromhtml)
```

So your code will be:

```
Polls.update({
    _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(id),
    'Orders.User': user
}, {
    $set: {
        'Orders.$': {
            User: user,
            Order: order,
            Amount: parseFloat(amount)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that bug is, but you have no need for "overwriting" your entire object with that update, which could be what causes this. You can just update the only two properties that are actually subject to change:

```
Polls.update(
  {_id: id, 'Orders.User': user},
  {$set:
    {'Orders.$.Order': order, 'Orders.$.Amount': parseFloat(amount)}
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) to false:

```
Polls.update({_id: id, 'Orders.User': user},
             {$set:
                 {'Orders.$':
                   {
                     User: user,
                     Order: order,
                     Amount: parseFloat(amount)
                   }
                 }
             },
             { upsert: false });
```

If this don't work, try with `upsert: false` on BraveKenny's answer.

I hope this helps.